# EKS Terraform - datasource aws_eks_cluster_auth - token expired

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I've an EKS cluster deployed in AWS and I use terraform to deploy components to that cluster.

In order to get authenticated I'm using the following [EKS datasources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/eks_cluster_auth) that provides the cluster API Authentication:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = var.cluster_id
}

data "aws_vpc" "eks_vpc" {
  id = var.vpc_id
}
```

And using the token inside several `local-exec` provisioners (apart of other resources) to deploy components

```
resource "null_resource" "deployment" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = path.module
    command     = <<EOH
kubectl \
  --server="${data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint}" \
  --certificate-authority=./ca.crt \
  --token="${data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token}" \
  apply -f test.yaml
EOH
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that some resources are taking a little while to deploy and at some point when terraform executes the next resource I get this error because the token has expired:

```
exit status 1. Output: error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Is there a way to force re-creation of the `data` before running the `local-exec`s?

Comment: Which resources in particular take a long time? You can try ordering them using depends_on relations such that the the `deployment` can run directly after the `aws_eks_cluster_auth`

Comment: Hi! I've some resources like fargate_profiles, helm-charts, load balancers etc I've tried to order but some of the components have strong dependencies that needs to be executed first.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE: example moved to https://github.com/aidanmelen/terraform-kubernetes-rbac/blob/main/examples/authn_authz/main.tf

The `data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster_auth.token` creates a token with a non-configurable 15 minute timeout.

One way to get around this is to use the sts token to create a long-lived service-account token and use that to provision the terraform-kubernetes-provider for long running kuberenetes resources.

I created a module called [terraform-kubernetes-service-account](https://github.com/aidanmelen/terraform-kubernetes-service-account) to capture this common behavior of creating a service account, giving it some permissions, and output the auth information i.e. `token`, `ca.crt`, `namespace`.

For example:

```
module "terraform_admin" {
  source = "aidanmelen/service-account/kubernetes"

  name               = "terraform-admin"
  namespace          = "kube-system"
  cluster_role_name  = "terraform-admin"
  cluster_role_rules = [
    {
      api_groups     = ["*"]
      resources      = ["*"]
      resource_names = ["*"]
      verbs          = ["*"]
    },
  ]
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "terraform_admin_service_account"
  host                   = "https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443"
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.terraform_admin.auth["ca.crt"]
  token                  = module.terraform_admin.auth["token"]
}

data "kubernetes_namespace_v1" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = kubernetes_namespace.ex_complete.metadata[0].name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `aws_eks_cluster_auth` token is valid for ~15 minutes only. So to extend the token lifetime automatically, you can use below approach, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/fcb4256fa17b3e0bde8bbd69dfd191414977f30c/examples/complete/main.tf#L5-L15)

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks.cluster_name]
    command     = "aws"
  }
}
```

In case of adding IAM role to args, update it as:

```
args = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks.cluster_name, "--role-arn", var.iam_role_arn]
```